# RTL lookup from extension until " or = is hit

Tags: json, regex

I have a web application which processes file uploads. Upon extracting the file names this can be in formats such as

```
["attachment; filename=","New Microsoft Excel Worksheet.xlsx",""]
["attachment; filename=","/New Microsoft Excel Worksheet.xlsx/",""]
["attachment; filename="jimmy.xlsx""]
["attachment; filename=jimmy.xlsx]
```

I was initially only aware of example 2 and so did a lookup for all characters between the scape slashes

```
(?<=\/)(.*?)(?=\/)
```

However I need something that would in the examples above output either

```
New Microsoft Excel Worksheet.xlsx
```

OR

```
jimmy.xlsx
```

I.e.  reading the string from right to left starting past file extension and ending at either " or =

Comment: One way could be excluding what you allow to match `[^\s\/"=][^".=]*\.\w+` https://regex101.com/r/SbdvNQ/1

Comment: Or, `filename=(?:",)?"?/?\K[^]/"]+` - [demo](https://regex101.com/r/zjubmj/1).

Comment: What is the programming language?

Comment: Another option: [`([^=",\/]*)[",\/]*$`](https://regex101.com/r/qMboZm/1)

Comment: I can find another "how to parse content disposition field" (that's the name of the format) as a duplicate but what language are you using? There is 100% a parser for this for it that'll always work and deal with quirky encoding edge cases for you.

Answer (score 0):

The pattern `(?<=\/)(.*?)(?=\/)` only matches between 2 mandatory forward slashes which is only present in 1 of the example strings.

Looking at your posted anwser, one option could be matching word characters with whitespace chars in between and match one or more dots followed by word characters.

```
\w+(?:\s+\w+)*(?:\.\w+)+
```

Another option could be to match not allowed characters, and end the match with a dot and word characters.

```
[^/\s"=\][][^/"=\][]*\.\w+
```

- `[^/\s"=\][]` Start the match with a non whitespace char, except for `/` `"` `=` `[` `]`
- `[^/"=\][]*` The same as before, now allowing a whitespace char
- `\.` Match a `.`
- `\w+` Match 1 or more word characters

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/5h8k1U/1)

Or using a capture group, making the match more specific and for example leaving out matching a dot and word characters at the end.

```
\bfilename=[",/]*([^/\s"=\][][^/"=\][]*)
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/LL2y3N/1)

Answer (score 0):

Solved using the following regex thanks to:

https://www.reddit.com/user/CryptoOTC_creator/

```
[\w\s]+\.[\.\w\d]+



[Character set. Match any character in the set.
\w Word. Matches any word character (alphanumeric & underscore).
\s Whitespace. Matches any whitespace character (spaces, tabs, line breaks).
] 
+Quantifier. Match 1 or more of the preceding token.
\.Escaped character. Matches a "." character (char code 46).
[Character set. Match any character in the set.
\.Escaped character. Matches a "." character (char code 46).
\w Word. Matches any word character (alphanumeric & underscore).
\d Digit. Matches any digit character (0-9).
] 
+Quantifier. Match 1 or more of the preceding token.
```

Comment: In that case, the pattern can be `[\w\s]+\.[\.\w]+` as `\w` also matches `\d` Note that the pattern could possible also match just a space and 2 dots.